# SQL Query OR and AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that uses OR and AND at the same time. I am using PDO.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=helpinghands', 'root', '');
        $table = $conn->query("SELECT
            a1.nickname as lv1_1,
            a2.nickname as lv1_2,
            a3.nickname as lv1_3,
            a4.nickname as lv1_4,
            a5.nickname as lv1_5,
            a6.nickname as lv1_6,
            a7.nickname as lv1_7,
            a8.nickname as lv1_8,
            a9.nickname as lv2_1,
            a10.nickname as lv2_2,
            a11.nickname as lv2_3,
            a12.nickname as lv2_4,
            a13.nickname as lv3_1,
            a14.nickname as lv3_2,
            a15.nickname as lv4
            FROM tables as t
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a1 ON t.l1_1=a1.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON t.l1_2=a2.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a3 ON t.l1_3=a3.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a4 ON t.l1_4=a4.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a5 ON t.l1_5=a5.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a6 ON t.l1_6=a6.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a7 ON t.l1_7=a7.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a8 ON t.l1_8=a8.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a9 ON t.l2_1=a9.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a10 ON t.l2_2=a10.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a11 ON t.l2_3=a11.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a12 ON t.l2_4=a12.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a13 ON t.l3_1=a13.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a14 ON t.l3_2=a14.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a15 ON t.l4=a15.sponsorID
            WHERE
            (t.l1_1 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR 
            t.l1_2 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_3 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_4 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_5 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_6 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_7 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_8 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_1 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_2 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_3 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_4 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l3_1 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l3_2 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l4 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . ") AND status = '1'
            ");
```

If the `AND status = '1'` is not there, it is working. But I need to query with the `status` field so I can output only a specific field. How can I accomplish that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: status belongs to which table?

Comment: @NikhilBatra status belongs to table "tables"

Comment: Have you tried using t.status?

Comment: @NikhilBatra Ya I forgot lol. Works now thanks!

Comment: Your db design is horrible. Have one row for each l1_1, perhaps in separate table. Then the query will be much easier to write.

Comment: @jarlh That hurts but it is true.. will try to do it better. THANKS

Comment: @jarlh What do you mean 1 row for each l1_1?

Comment: Have a separate table for the l1_1, etc fields. In that table you have one row per value (not one row that has a column for each value). Then you just join the table _tables_ to this new table to get each value. Means that you can have as many l1_1, etc, fields as you want without adding new columns when the max number changes, plus makes it easy to check if one of them is a particular sponsor id

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=helpinghands', 'root', '');
        $table = $conn->query("SELECT
            a1.nickname as lv1_1,
            a2.nickname as lv1_2,
            a3.nickname as lv1_3,
            a4.nickname as lv1_4,
            a5.nickname as lv1_5,
            a6.nickname as lv1_6,
            a7.nickname as lv1_7,
            a8.nickname as lv1_8,
            a9.nickname as lv2_1,
            a10.nickname as lv2_2,
            a11.nickname as lv2_3,
            a12.nickname as lv2_4,
            a13.nickname as lv3_1,
            a14.nickname as lv3_2,
            a15.nickname as lv4
            FROM tables as t
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a1 ON t.l1_1=a1.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON t.l1_2=a2.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a3 ON t.l1_3=a3.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a4 ON t.l1_4=a4.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a5 ON t.l1_5=a5.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a6 ON t.l1_6=a6.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a7 ON t.l1_7=a7.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a8 ON t.l1_8=a8.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a9 ON t.l2_1=a9.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a10 ON t.l2_2=a10.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a11 ON t.l2_3=a11.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a12 ON t.l2_4=a12.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a13 ON t.l3_1=a13.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a14 ON t.l3_2=a14.sponsorID
            LEFT JOIN accounts AS a15 ON t.l4=a15.sponsorID
            WHERE
            (t.l1_1 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR 
            t.l1_2 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_3 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_4 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_5 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_6 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_7 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l1_8 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_1 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_2 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_3 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l2_4 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l3_1 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l3_2 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . " OR
            t.l4 = " . $conn->quote($session->sponsorID) . ") AND t.status = '1'
            ");
```